# Rashi on Tractate Avot

Tags: rashi, authorship, pirke-avot-ethicsof

As mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15520/which-masechtot-dont-really-have-rashi/15574#15574) the commentary attributed to [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) on [Avot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_Avot) may not have been authored by him.

This is stated by [R. Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) in the introduction to "Ets Avot".

Which other sources state that the commentary was not authored by him?

Comment: @user6591 the popular red avos with rishonim, in the introduction, cites the Shem Hagedolim as saying the opposite; that it **was** authored by Rashi.

Comment: @user6591 to quote the said ed. וגם התוס' בפי' התורה כת"י מיחסים אותו לרש"י

Comment: Just had the opportunity to check the red Avos. It quotes Chida as you say. So does the Artscroll on Avos. So my comment based on a false memory has been removed. Both sources also quote a plurality of opinions doubting Rashi's authorship, but only quote the Yaavetz, so +1.

Comment: I remember vaguely a rule in regards to the authorship of Rashi, if it doesn't say Rashi then it's actual Rashi,and of the periush says Rashi then it isn't Rashi,except for shas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this short introduction](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?155106) (by R. Mordechai Katzenelnbogen) regarding the commentary of Rashi (page 6 on the site; page 10 of the actual book). He only quotes R. Yaakov Emden (as you did) and R. Tzvi Hirsch Chajes as arguing against the authenticity of the commentary to Avot. But he is certain that Rashi did indeed author a commentary to Avos and attributes their arguments to the inaccuracy of the versions that they had.