# Why is there no Rashi on Maseches Nedarim, Nazir, most of Bava Basra etc?

Tags: rashi, talmud-bavli, rishonim

A similar question asked "[Which masechtot don't really have Rashi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15520/which-masechtot-dont-really-have-rashi)" which proceeded to list the *Masechtot* (*Nedarim*, *Nazir*, *Moed Kattan*) & parts of *Shas* (most of *Bava Basra*, last 4 *daf* of *Makkos*) that **don't** have Rashi's commentary.

Do we know why we don't have Rashi's commentary for these *Masechtot*? (I know [he "died" a few times in *Shas*](https://twitter.com/AsherBecker/status/937457144777134080))

Were they not written? Did we lose them at some point? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I had always thought that he was in middle of several tractates at the same time, thus when he died, there was an abrupt stop in the aforementioned  uncompleted tractates.

Comment: Right- so is that the reason? He died before he could get to them/ complete them? (and if so, is there a source for that's the reason why we don't have them?)

Comment: If I recall correctly, in one of the Masechtot, Rashba"m (who I think was Rashi's grandson?) comments something like, "Don't pay attention to what Rash"i said on such a page. He was senile when he wrote that..."

Comment: Please source that.