# Did Rashi die while working on multiple tractates?

Tags: commentaries, rashi

I've seen printed in some גמראs that רש"י died, and another פרוש follows. Is there any evidence to support this? Is it possible that רש"י's commentary was partially lost in some tractates?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98966/why-is-there-no-rashi-on-maseches-nedarim-nazir-most-of-bava-basra-etc

Comment: The evidence is that is what the Gemara claims. If it was partially lost, why would it be lost only at the end and not the beginning or middle. And I don't see why Rashi couldn't work on multiple tractates at once.

Comment: @N.T. Well, I saw something in דקדוקי סופרים that it seemed to say that we have *nonconsecutive fragments* of Rashi on בבא בתרא, and the rest is the רשב״ם.

Comment: @RaphiSpoerri That's not what most people assume. Can you show me the citation? Remember, Rashi and Rashbam to Bava Basra are stylistically very far apart. Rashi is short and succinct as always, and the Rashbam is much, much longer, and explains in much more detail.