# טירטוריו"ש in Rashi

Tags: talmud-gemara, words, rashi, talmud-bavli, maseches-nazir

[In his commentary to Nazir 49b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=49b&format=pdf) (heading קנטרנין), Rashi gives one word: **טירטוריו"ש**

What does this word mean please?

Comment: Note I don't think Rashi wrote a commentary on Nazir

Comment: @robev https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15520/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.49b.5?lang=bi&with=Otzar%20Laazei%20Rashi&lang2=en)

> Otzar Laazei Rashi, Talmud, Nazir 6
> 1212 / (נזיר מט:) / קנטרנין
> טורטוריו"ש גורמי-נזק, עושי-עוול / torurios
> ✭ offenders, transgressors, malicious people

Comment: I had no idea that was even on Sefaria! Thank you

Comment: Just looking at the old French source in comparison to the definition from the Otzar, it seems to derive from “torturers”, meaning those who torture others. If you look at the Hebrew root (קנטר) in Jastrow in addition to vexing people, it also relates to a type of Angel of Destruction that plagues the wicked and also to a pronged tool like a plumber’s auger. In Rashi’s day, augers were also used as torture devices on people.

Answer (score 4):

תרגום הלע"ז by Dayan Yisroel Kukovitzky of London a dictionary of all French words in Rashi translated into Hebrew, French and English sources the Gemoroh 49: and brings both spellings
מזיק לאחרים torturios,
who do harm to others,
qui font tort aux autres, injustes