# Mefaresh on Nedarim - author

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, rashi, authorship, tractate-nedarim

I have potential heard that the mefresh on nedarim is not Rashi. If so, who is the author? Is there a clear source that it is not Rashi?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15520/759

Comment: @DoubleAA no source or proof foe nedarim is provided there

Comment: רש״י = ראשון שאינו ידוע

Comment: "The foremost medieval commentator on the Talmud was Rabbi Shlomoh Yitzchaki (1040-1105), commonly known by the acronym of his name, “Rashi.” However, it is today generally understood that the commentary traditionally printed on the Talmudic page of Nedarim 20ab as “Rashi” was not actually penned by him, but by an unknown writer, referred to in rabbinic literature as “Mefaresh" - Yaakov Shapiro

Comment: A great resource to check if you want to know what Rashi wrote and didn't write is the Chida's sefer "Shem Hagedolim" under the section titled Rashi. He discusses all of the sefarim in Tanach as well as all the masechtos that are questionably written by Rashi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a brief discussion about this in the beginning of Metivta edition of massechet Nedarim, I'll summarize it here:

The commentary on Nedarim which is referred to as "Rashi commentary" was first printed in 1521 in Veneza in the first ever Talmud print (see wikipedia for [Talmud Bomberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Bomberg#Publication_of_the_Babylonian_Talmud_(1519-23))).

The first person to hold that the Nedarim commentary was not from Rashi was [Rabenu Betzalel Ashkenazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezalel_Ashkenazi) (author of Shitat Mekubetzet), as written by his student [Rabenu Shlomo Adeni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Adeni), author of the book "Melechet Shlomo".

The [Chida (Haim Yosef David Azulai)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) also argues in his book "Shem HaGuedolim" that Nedarim commentary is not actually from Rashi and also proves it from the difference in the language used by this commentary and other Rashi commentaries in other massechtot. There he points out that also the Beit Yossef when referring to this commentary refers it as only "the commenter", which he wouldn't do when refering to Rashi. Also the [Yaabetz (Rabbi Jacob Emden)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden) and [Maharatz Hayot (Rabbi Tzvi Hirsch Chajes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvi_Hirsch_Chajes) both write that the commentary is not from Rashi.

Rabi [Tzadok HaKohen from Lublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zadok_HaKohen) in his responsa Tiferet Tzvi (part 2, 21:3) writes that the commentary in massechet Nedarim is from [Rabenu Guershom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_ben_Judah) or at least was taken from his commentary [fun fact: from pages 22b to 25b the commentary is for sure from Rabenu Guershom, as is written explicitly in the Rashi section].

Also, some rishonim indeed quote Rashi in massechet Nedarim, that suggests that Rashi indeed wrote some commentary for Nedarim and, in fact, some parts of Rashi commentary in massechet Nedarim were copied by Rabenu Betzalel Ashkenazi in his notes of massechet Nedarim and on his book Shitat Mekubetzet.

Comment: +1. In addition, Rabbeinu Avraham min Hahar quotes Rashi very often in his commentary, and it does not appear in our Rashi in Nedarim. What he quotes is consistent with Rashi's opinions in Maseches Shavuos however, as I argued here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dUnp92KvxpTwgv1DJDLhR0wu5Ob_04sw-LpLjPqXnBA/edit?usp=sharing  (I have a much longer version with the proofs developed if you want.)

Comment: Several blatt of Rashi's genuine commentary are preserved in the Schlessinger manuscript (the notes you mention) and these have been printed in the back of the MhRK edition. This version matches up with the quotations of  R Avraham min haHar.